# Error installing kernel from source!

Tags: kernel

I compiled the latest Linux Kernel (4.5.x) from Linus's git tree. The Kernel compiled perfectly with no errors. After compiling the kernel I installed the modules using `sudo make modules_install`. That worked flawlessly too; however when I run `sudo make install` it gives me this error.

```
 sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver4.bin for module i915

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.5.0-00001-gf99c49a with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:189: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:260: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I followed these three links: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314755/e-mkinitramfs-failure-cpio-141-gzip-1), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38083/initramfs-problem-when-out-of-disk-space) and  [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223248/gzip-stdout-no-space-left-on-device-while-upgrading-the-kernel); but they don't solve the problem.

I think space (in `/boot`) is the issue as sometimes I get a warning which says that there is only 24 MB space left in `/boot` however `df` shows :-

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1833688         0   1833688   0% /dev
tmpfs             395944     23612    372332   6% /run
/dev/dm-0      475786312 234152100 217442632  52% /
tmpfs            1979716      1052   1978664   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1979716         0   1979716   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2         650875    398220    219070  65% /boot
/dev/sda1         102178      7236     94942   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs             395944        60    395884   1% /run/user/1000
```

NOTE: i am currently running Linux Kernel `4.5.0-rc1` and this error only shows up when I compile the kernel with `make oldconfig`. If I use `make defconfig` then everything works fine.

EDIT 1: Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Do you have a config settings that specifies how big the make the initramfs?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not aware of any such setting. Maybe i can `grep` it if you ell me the string.

Comment: I don't know off hand. It's just that the error message could be about the size of the boot partition or about the size of the initramfs, which might explain the difference between configs. Probably it is just runing out of space in /boot.

Comment: I suggest you retry the command with `make DESTDIR=/somewhere/else ...blah...` and see if it still fails when there's more space to play with.

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: I edited the question to include the distro also and I will try the DESTDIR ... Thing and update soon!

Comment: The message says that you don't have enough room in `/boot`. So make some. The difference between configurations is presumably that `defconfig` compiles fewer modules to include in the initramfs.

Comment: Yeah!! it worked. The space in `/boot` was the issue. The initrd image is huge (>250 mb) but that is another question.